# target location specified by path segment was not found with json patch

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a view model with a one of the property name written as:

```
public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
```

During the JSON patch user sends the request as:

```
{

 "op": "replace",
 "value": "4056666666",
 "path": "/fax_number"
}
```

I have implemented the patch method as:

```
public async Task<int> PatchAddressAsync(int id, JsonPatchDocument<Address> request)
{
    var cust = await _dbContext.Address.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ID == id);

    if (cust == null)
        throw new NotFoundException($"The supplied id is not valid.");

    request.ApplyTo(cust);

    _dbContext.Address.Update(cust);

    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(default(CancellationToken));
    return cust.ID;
}
```

But my problem is I have a different name for the column fax name in the address entity, which is defined as:

```
[Column("fax")]
public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
```

Now when i tires to `request.ApplyTo(cust);` it gives me error:

> The target location specified by path segment 'fax_number' was not
> found.

How do I model my entity and path in this case? How can use the property that is mapped with the view model but not that is matched with the entity?

Comment: The only way I can think of is creating a new model, say AddressDTO with the desired property name, setting up a mapping between the EF core model and DTO, transform EF core model to DTO, apply JSONPatch to DTO and then transform DTO back to EF core model to commit changes to db. Happy to stand corrected !!

Comment: it sounds like a recurssion. Any code could be helpful.

Comment: It's not recursion. Just a proxy model that has the desired property names

Comment: you can refer the following article to [use Automapper with JSON Patch](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/11/29/json-patch-asp-net-core/), then create a DTO model and use automapper to map the database object and the view model.